# AWS instance schedulewith auto scaling groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I've configured AWS instance scheduler, everything is working as expected.

The issue I'm having is each instance has a autoscaling group in my dev environment and i'm unable to shutdown instances without them beign terminated by autoscale group when it does a health check and notices its down.

Has anyone figured out an automated solution to this without me having to manually suspend ASG? Since the whole purpose of this is to stop the instances after hours I'm unable to intervene to suspend/resume ASG.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS instance scheduler"? Are you wanting to Stop or Terminate the instances? Why don't you just reduce the Desired Capacity of the Auto Scaling group and let it terminate them?

Comment: AWS has a cloud formation template called Instance Scheduler that allows you to be able to stop/start instances based on a predefined schedule. Right now when my schedule kicks in and stops these instances , ASG detects that theyre down , terminates them and recreates it as running. So I'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate ASG so it can handle this scenario or  last resort get rid of ASG for dev environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Auto Scaling" and "AWS Instance Scheduler" don't really fit together nicely. Do you really need ELB for Dev environments? I feel this is overkill.

Anyway, if you still want to use ELB + AutoScaling and would like to shutdown the boxes during off hours, you can set "AutoScaling" to ZERO for the hours you want using [Scheduled Scaling approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html).

Comment: any suggestion how i could setup the Auto scaling schedule? I see it has a start and end time which includes dates but i need this to run everyday with no end date/start date but seems its mandatory.

Comment: I think "end date" is optional. Did you try not setting it? If it is required, just set some future date like 2020. If set as "recurrence", it will happen daily at specified time. Good luck!